# Runtime Error : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

am trying to redirect the page in ionic3. I have used this.navCtrl.push(TemplesPage); but it is showing error "Runtime Error: Cannot read property push of undefined". please help me on this.

Thanks

```
ngOnInit(){
this.task = setInterval(function () {
 this.navCtrl.push(TemplesPage);
}, 3000);
}
```

When the app open first it displays logo, after 3 seconds it redirects to home page, this is what am trying to develop.

Comment: Hey Sasi, your code uses "interval" which is weird:) I think you definitely meant something else.  The issue with your code is that you are using anonymous function and that function creates its own "this" scope, thus when inside you function you call this.navCtrl - "this" there is no longer pointing at your class. You need to use fat arrow function exactly how the answer below states. Fat arrow functions do not create their own 'this' scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this method. I hope it fix.[Ionic 3]

```js
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '/home';

class MyComponent {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  openOtherPage(){
      setTimeout(() => { 
          this.navCtrl.push(HomePage) 
       }, 5000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Page must redirects after few seconds, but now it is not redirecting

Comment: you can use loader

Comment: setTimeout(() => {
        this.navCtrl.push(HomePage)
  }, 5000);

Comment: Look now Editted